# PHP : Cropping a selected text from a string

Tags: php

I want to get the string part of a URL cropping off **http://** like from http://google.com I need to crop http:// and get google.com.

I used the following code an it gives me /google.com

```
strrchr("http://google.com" , "//");
```

how can I do this? ow can I get only google.com

**Update: ** Google.com is just an example, the url can be a long url like http://artile.blogspot.com/article.htm so i need article.blogspot.com/article.htm

Comment: Use `parse_url('http://google.com',PHP_URL_HOST)` instead.

Comment: parse_url (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: well google.com is just an example, it can be a long url so i won't be able to use parse url isn't it?

Comment: @Rukshan or use `str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',$url);`

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone it works :) str_replace will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just look to see if the string starts with `http://` and then use a function to get the remaining sub-string?

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0) {
    $url = substr($url, 7);
}
```

---

If there are other prefixes that you would like to remove, then perhaps it might be time to start looking into a quick regex to get the job done. For example:

```
$url = 'https://google.com';
$url = preg_replace('#^(?:https?|ftps?|news|feed|gopher)://#', '', $url);
```

Comment: this also works, thanks :) str_replace will also do the trick

Answer (score 2):

The function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is what you're looking for.

As Lawrence says, the exact code will be:

```
$host = parse_url('http://google.com',PHP_URL_HOST);
```

An alternative would be [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$host = str_replace("http://", "", "http://google.com", 1);
```

The fourth parameter(`count`) makes sure that it'll only replace the *first* instance of `http://`

Comment: what if the url is something like this. http://artile.blogspot.com/artile.htm so I need to skip the http:// part and need the rest of the URL. so the following wouldn't work isn't it?

Comment: The question says that the only part of the string is the URL.

Comment: @SomeKittens that's not how the `$count` parameter works, it needs to be a variable which gets populated with the number of replacements. If you want to limit the number of replacements, use `preg_replace()` but then you can just anchor the regex to the start of the subject string.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `[^http://]+$`